# How could i open a mp4 file using command line in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, cmd

i want to open a **mp4** file with **vlc** . I want to try it with *command line* but i didn't find anything. Is there any command with which I could open it ?

Comment: This is not a programming question, so it is not appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Start foo.mp4 should do the trick

Comment: @Marged, `foo.mp4` should work without `start`. You could also add `.MP4` to `PATHEXT` to just run `foo`.

Comment: Yes , it works but the file is opening with media player . I try this ,
C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe foo.mp4 but when vlc opened , there were errors :(

Comment: @Chryssa   In this case it depends what you want to change. Either call `C:\Progra~1\Videolan\VLC.exe C:\foo\bar.mp4` (or whereever videolan is installed on your PC) or use `assoc` and `ftype` to have vlc mapped to .mp4. If you don't know where vlc.exe was installed it will become difficult and you will have to search for the exe

Comment: @eryksun This depends on if you want the batch to wait until vlc has stopped or not ;-)

Comment: @Marged, yes, but the OP said at the "command line" and the question isn't tagged batch-file. That's part of why I voted to close, but even if it were about a batch file it's so tangentially related to programming that I still would have voted to close.

Comment: @eryksun you are correct, I mixed this up with a different question I replied to in parallel and this question was about batches

Answer (score 2):

When using paths with spaces it must be enclosed in quotes.

Also you need to specify the full path to the files. Also there are variables to point to consisant places. So if foo.mp4 is on the desktop.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop\foo.mp4"
```

or if somewhere on a USB

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "G:\Vids\foo.mp4"
```